# Inferring props type for a component in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that takes one fixed prop and one that can be random. When it comes to typing the component, I'd want to play it type safe and avoid just using *any* for the addition props. Here's what I have in mind:

App.tsx:

```
<Button component='button' href='x'>
    Push Me
</Button>
```

Button.tsx:

```
import { type PropsWithChildren, type ElementType, type FC } from 'react';

interface ButtonProps {
    component: ElementType;
    [key: string]: any;
}

export const Button: FC<PropsWithChildren<ButtonProps>> = ({
    component: Component,
    children,
    ...props
}) => {
    return <Component {...props}>{children}</Component>;
};
```

How can I remove the any from [key: string] and infer the additional props?

Answer (score 1):

If nesting the props under an object is allowed, then this works pretty well:

```js
import type {ComponentProps, ElementType} from "react";

type ButtonProps<T extends ElementType<any>> = {
    component: T,
    props: ComponentProps<T>,
};

export const Button = <T extends ElementType<any>>({
    component: Component,
    props,
}: ButtonProps<T>) => {
    return <Component {...props} />
};

const MyComponent = (props: {a: number, b: number}) => {
    return <p>{props.a} + {props.b} = {props.a + props.b}</p>
}

<Button component={MyComponent} props={{a: 4, b: 5}} />;

// there is a typescript error here because 'button' doesn't support 'href'
<Button component='button' props={{href: 'x'}}>
    Push Me
</Button>
```

If nesting under an object is not an option then I think you can't get full type safety. I've tried hacking at it for a while with mostly no luck. It seems typescript isn't really great at validating `Omit` spread types haha.

Comment: This is very interesting, I'm gonna try it. You're right, href doesn't exist under button, but that was my point, TS shouldn't allow something like this to exist. The proper props should've been link for a component type and href for component props but I intentionally left it like to see if it caused error.

Comment: @Zachiach There's a missing support for children, btw. Otherwise this seems to be the right direction, but there's still something missing. TS can't tell which type of component the props belong to. But it definitely seems like this could lead to the answer I was looking for.

Comment: please elaborate on "TS can't tell which type of component the props belong to". I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

give a try to following .

```
import { PropsWithChildren, ElementType, FC, HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

interface ButtonProps extends Omit<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, 'component'> {
  component: ElementType;
}

export const Button: FC<PropsWithChildren<ButtonProps>> = ({
  component: Component,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  return <Component {...props}>{children}</Component>;
};
```

and let me know if any ?

Edit : i have seen the @zachiah 's answer and it looks interesting but i am giving it try as a more simplify solution ,i welcome if any one highlights issue and explain problem in the below approach.

```
import { PropsWithChildren, ElementType, FC } from 'react';

type ButtonProps<T extends ElementType> = {
  component: T;
  props: React.ComponentProps<T>;
};

export const Button = <T extends ElementType>({
  component: Component,
  ...props
}: PropsWithChildren<ButtonProps<T>>) => {
  return <Component {...props.props}>{props.children}</Component>;
};
```

and the html part:

```
<Button component="button" props={{ type: "submit" }}>
  Push Me
</Button>
```

Comment: While this answer isn't strictly "correct". I'm liking it more and more as I attempt to implement the "correct" answer...

Comment: It's an appropriate answer, but my goal (which I admit should've been better defined) was to be able to pass any type of component into Button and only allow props that come with it, not specificallly for link, but for any one.

Comment: see the edit part and let me know it i got your intension correct or not ?